# I have a field with current/permanent_address and I need to use this field with forward slash in my serializer

Tags: django, serialization

**this is my serializer and I am not able to declare fields in my serilizer with forward slash**

```
  "address": {
                        "current/permenantAddress": {
                            "PERM_LINE1": "delhi vasant vihar",
                            "PERM_LINE2": "vasant vihar",
                        },
                        "correspondence/localAddress": {
                            "CORRES_LINE1": "",
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare fields in your serializer when dealing with field names that contain forward slashes:

for example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class AddressSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    current_permanentAddress = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    correspondence_localAddress = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_current_permanentAddress(self, obj):
        return {
            "PERM_LINE1": obj.get("address/current/permenantAddress/PERM_LINE1", ""),
            "PERM_LINE2": obj.get("address/current/permenantAddress/PERM_LINE2", ""),
        }

    def get_correspondence_localAddress(self, obj):
        return {
            "CORRES_LINE1": obj.get("address/correspondence/localAddress/CORRES_LINE1", ""),
        }
```

I define two fields, **current_permanentAddress** and **correspondence_localAddress**, using **SerializerMethodField**. These fields call custom methods, **get_current_permanentAddress**, and **get_correspondence_localAddress**, respectively, which extract values from the nested field names with forward slashes using the obj.get() method.